# Is it okay/not okay to add more repositories?

Tags: raspbian-buster, kali, repository

I am using Raspbian Buster.Assume I have added kali-linux repositories in my source list. y question is ,
1.What are the risks of adding two different repositories in one OS?
2.Is it going to corrupt my OS or software?
3.How to maintain more than one repositories?

Comment: As long as the repos are for the right machine architecture then there should be no harm. Ask the folks who created the repo.

Comment: Just make sure the Raspbian Buster entry is at the top of the sources.list so that it is given priority when installing.

Answer (score 3):

A Debian repository is mainly made for a specific distribution and even for a specific version of it. For Raspbian/Debian you will find different repositories e.g. for version Jessie (or old-old-stable), Stretch (or old-stable) , Buster (or stable) and so on. The packages in the repository are pre compiled for the version and the installable executable programs fit optimal into its environment. This way you can just `sudo apt install myprogram` without the need to compile it. The disadvantage is that this pre compiled programs only fit to the distribution they are compiled for. You can add for example the repository for kali-linux to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and you should also be able to update the package lists with `sudo apt update`. Afterwards you will find the packages for kali-linux in addition to the packages for Raspbian with `apt list`. But if you install a package for kali-linux (as far as `apt` doesn't complain dependency errors) and try to run it, it will often crash with **segmentation fault** because kernel, modules and libraries from Raspbian doesn't fit.

You can find specific repositories which are explicitly made to run on different distributions. They are smaller and mostly support only one application, maybe with optional packages and plugins. But they have to be labeled that they are independent from a distribution so you can use it.

Comment: I think it would be unusual for an executable from one reasonably recent debian derived distro to seg fault on another of the same architecture *if* it links and runs:  The most common problem would be trying to use stuff from a distro that is ahead in terms of component versioning, in which case an executable may not link because shared libraries are not considered forward compatible.  In that case you can try and then install all the libraries from the other distro, but this can be quite a ball of yarn and is not always feasible.